# Tornado - How to get response of AsynHTTPClient.fetch()?

Tags: python, debugging, http, web, tornado

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpclient

import urllib
import json
import datetime
import time

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

config = {
        'proxy_host': '58.59.21.228',
        'proxy_port': 25,
        'proxy_username': 'yz',
        'proxy_password': 'fangbinxingqusi',
}

def handle_request(response):
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error

tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = client.fetch("http://twitter.com/", handle_request,
                **config)
        self.write(response.body)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)],
            debug=True)
    httpserver = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    httpserver.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

At running, `response` object in the `get()` method is reported to be a `None` type. How can I get the response of the `fetch()` method in the `get()` method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the [AsyncHTTPClient](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html?highlight=asynchttpclient#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient), therefore the `fetch` method does not return anything. You need to use the "asynchronous" decorator and remember to call `finish` in the callback called by `fetch`.

Here is the code:

```
import tornado.httpserver                                                    
import tornado.ioloop                                                        
import tornado.options                                                       
import tornado.web                                                           
import tornado.httpclient                                                    

from tornado.options import define, options                                  
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)         

config = {                                                                   
    'proxy_host': '58.59.21.228',                                            
    'proxy_port': 25,                                                        
    'proxy_username': 'yz',                                                  
    'proxy_password': 'fangbinxingqusi',                                     
}                                                                            

tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")


class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):                              

    @tornado.web.asynchronous                                                
    def get(self):                                                           
        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()                        
        client.fetch("http://twitter.com/", self.handle_request, **config)   

    def handle_request(self, response):                                      
        if response.error:                                                   
            print("Error:", response.error)                                  
        else:                                                                
            self.write(response.body)                                        
        self.finish()                                                        


if __name__ == "__main__":                                                   
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()                                     
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)], debug=True)
    httpserver = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)                          
    httpserver.listen(options.port)                                          
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

You can also use [Tornado's gen](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html?highlight=gen#tornado.gen) to make your handler prettier:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):                              

    @tornado.web.asynchronous                                                
    @tornado.gen.engine                                                      
    def get(self):                                                           
        client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()                        
        response = yield tornado.gen.Task(client.fetch, "http://twitter.com/",
                                        **config)                            
        if response.error:                                                   
            self.write("Error: %s" % response.error)                         
        else:                                                                
            self.write(response.body)                                        

        self.finish()
```